# Python flask how to display list of items in html template

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, for-loop

i am following [flask template](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/templates/#id1)  to display a list of items in my html template but the for loop only displaying last value
`{'reference': 'Customer/bJxi0A3', 'display': 'TEST, Beacon'}`
from the list below can't understand why ?

```
{'reference': 'Customer/uH50Lnw3', 'display': 'DEFVERIFYTESTONE, Awiltthirtyfive'}
{'reference': 'Customer/eereURJQ3', 'display': 'FITTESTTWO, Abcnsixteen'}
{'reference': 'Customer/URJQ3', 'display': 'FITTESTTWO, Abcnsixteen'}
{'reference': 'Customer/bJxi0A3', 'display': 'TEST, Beacon'}
```

**What do i need to do with this for loop to display all the values ?**

```
{% for item, value in customer.items(): %}
     <tr>
       <td>{{ item }}</td>
         <td>{{ value }}</td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another for loop, that goes through the list of all dicts.
For example:

```
dict_list = [{'reference': 'Customer/uH50Lnw3', 'display': 'DEFVERIFYTESTONE, Awiltthirtyfive'},
{'reference': 'Customer/eereURJQ3', 'display': 'FITTESTTWO, Abcnsixteen'},
{'reference': 'Customer/URJQ3', 'display': 'FITTESTTWO, Abcnsixteen'},
{'reference': 'Customer/bJxi0A3', 'display': 'TEST, Beacon'}]

{% for i in dict_list: %}
{% for item, value in i.items(): %}
     <tr>
       <td>{{ item }}</td>
         <td>{{ value }}</td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks what if i had no control over data it is not coming as a list and if i do convert it into a list my result is like ```dict_list = [{ }] [{ }] [{ }]```  instead of `[{}]`

Comment: Can you please be specific on how the data is coming, in what format ?

Comment: it is in ndjson format even with for loop you suggested it is still returning only the last value of the given list